# Stop the redirection after WooCommerce add to cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, product

I wish to completely remove any redirection after a user click on the ADD TO CART button.

Actually I am not using the products page. 
I am using a simple button with the link to the product, like this: **`?add-to-cart=492`**.

My user will click on several "add to cart" buttons on my page, so he cant be redirected to any page after clicking in the first button.

At the end of the page he will find a CHECKOUT button to pay and that is it.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:**

Your simple html "add-to-cart" button links are actually for example like that *(the **`href`** value)*:

```
<a href="http://my-domain.com/site2/?add-to-cart=492" target="_self" class="button white is-larger carrinho">
    <span>ESCOLHER PACOTE</span>
</a>
```

> So they are redirected each time to your home page

---

**2 SOLUTIONS:**

1) Use the [WooCommerce short code [add-to-cart]](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#section-10) this way:**

- Without price: **`[add_to_cart id="492" show_price="false"]`**
- With the price:  **`[add_to_cart id="492"]`**

2) **Html code** in your page text editor - **To prevent redirections,** the **`href` attribute** should be:

```
<a href="?add-to-cart=492" class="button white is-larger carrinho">
    <span>ESCOLHER PACOTE</span>
</a>
```

> This time **your customers will not be redirected as before**…

---

**THE CHECKOUT BUTTON**

**To finish,** here is a custom shortcode that will output the "Proceed to checkout" button:

```
if( !function_exists('proceed_to_checkout_button') ) {
    function proceed_to_checkout_button() {

        $checkout_url = wc_get_checkout_url();
        $button_txt = __('Proceed to checkout', 'woocommerce');

        $output = '<div class="wc-proceed-to-checkout">
            <a href="'. $checkout_url .'" class="checkout-button button alt wc-forward">
                '. $button_txt .'
            </a>
        </div>';

        return $output;
    }
    add_shortcode( 'checkout_button', 'proceed_to_checkout_button' );
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

> **Usage:** just add this to your pages editor: **`[checkout_button]`**

---

**Original answer:**

First, In WooCommerce settings you need to:

- Enable **Ajax on add-to-cart button (Woocommerce > Settings > Products > Display)
- Disable the **add-to-cart** button redirection (Woocommerce > Settings > Products > Display)

Then you can add a custom "Proceed to checkout" button using:

- Any classic WordPress menu (Appearance > Menus)
- With that custom code on single product pages and product archives:

```php
add_action('woocommerce_after_single_product', 'custom_checkout_button', 100);
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'custom_checkout_button', 100);
function custom_checkout_button() {

    $checkout_url = wc_get_checkout_url();
    $button_txt = __('Proceed to checkout', 'woocommerce');

    ?>
        <div class="wc-proceed-to-checkout">
            <a href="<?php echo $checkout_url; ?>" class="checkout-button button alt wc-forward">
                <?php echo $button_txt ?>
            </a>
        </div>
    <?php
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

The button "Proceed to checkout" will be show at the bottom of this pages.

---

If you want to skip the cart page:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'skip_cart_page_redirecting_to_checkout');
function skip_cart_page_redirecting_to_checkout() {

    // If is cart page and cart is not empty
    if( is_cart() && ! WC()->cart->is_empty() )
        wp_redirect( wc_get_checkout_url() );
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

All code is tested and works.

Comment: thanks, but the redirection after the add to cart button is pressed till happens. I am using a simple button in a regular page with the link = http://vendamais.me/site2/?add-to-cart=492. I dont know if that changes the logic of the solution or not...

Comment: after the add to cart button is clicked using that shortcode a "VIEW CART" text link replaces the button. Is there a way to change that text and even remove the link? see: http://take.ms/NzPhF
I managed to style it, but couldnt do more. thanks again

Comment: @rfmarchetti So is better to use  the html button in this case… You can even make your own shortcode easely…

Comment: thanks! I followed your instructions for that and created the link like this: <a href="?add-to-cart=492" and that stoped the redirection of the page, but the page refreshes after the click. Is is possible to remove even the refresh of the page? Like after the button is clicked the product is added to cart but nothing happens with the page?

Comment: @rfmarchetti That is not possible as it's a GET request that goes through the URL of your browser adding the product to cart. The only way is to use a GET (or a POST) request through AJAX to send the data without any browser refresh, but this is an advanced complicate development.

Comment: thanks @LoicTheAztec . I managed to get a great result with your help!

Answer (score 3):

Like in the woocommerce itself does in the product-code shortcode you could just use the filter for the simple-add to cart button 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_form_action'.

```
// Change form action to avoid redirect.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_form_action', '__return_empty_string' );
```