# Prevent Woocommerce Redirects to Product Page from add to cart

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce, product

I have a re-direct problem which is I think similar to [Stop the redirection after WooCommerce add to cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45248283/stop-the-redirection-after-woocommerce-add-to-cart/46829177#46829177) but also a bit different. I'm selling single tracks from digital albums. Each track has its own product page but is found and should be purchased through the page of the album to which it belongs. Its product ID is linked to its 'add to cart' button on the album page. When you add to cart a single track on the album page, you are re-directed to the page for the single track, which was not the plan. Can anyone give me a solution please that allows customers to stay on the album page? Woocommerce/products/display is set to no redirect to cart and AJAX is enabled. I'm a novice but can do stuff if it's clearly explained. Thanks.

Comment: No code examples provided. Downvoted.

Answer (score 2):

If no one is accessing those Track post types, go ahead and make them private. Otherwise, unless you take precaution, they are going to get indexed and people might even find them organically. You can fix this when you `register_post_type()`.

Additionally, you should be able to add this to you `functions.php` and get it going:

```
/**
 * Set a custom add to cart URL to redirect to
 * @return string
 */
function custom_add_to_cart_redirect() { 
    return 'http://www.yourdomain.com/your-page/'; 
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'custom_add_to_cart_redirect' );
```

This is straight from WooCommerce documentation.  Thanks!
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/set-a-custom-add-to-cart-url-to-redirect-to/

Comment: Sorry, unless I've completely misunderstood- possible, I don't think your answer addresses my question.

Comment: Add that code snippet to your `functions.php`. It will filter the page that gets redirected. This is the correct code. If you don't understand it, I am sorry.

Comment: Unsurprisingly that doesn't work. Please keep away from this thread you are clearly not interested in a two way communication. Thank you.

Comment: That's the code from WooCommerce documentation. I do this every day. That will work. Sorry you are having a hard time. Good luck

Comment: Did you edit the URL string, or did you just drop in `return 'http://www.yourdomain.com/your-page/';` Obviously that wouldnt work. You will have a to do some of the work yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Please add this line of code to your functions.php file it will disable the redirect functionality.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_redirect_single_search_result', '__return_false' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find an answer anywhere for the same problem so thought I'd post my solution here...

Assumption is you have enabled AJAX buttons and disabled redirect to checkout already in WooCommerce settings.

This part by itself would just refresh the current page instead of redirecting to a single product page:

```
// Filter Single Add to Cart Form Action
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_form_action', 'woo_filter_cart_redirect_action' );
function woo_filter_cart_redirect_action( $url ) {
    if ( is_tax( 'product_cat' ) ) {
        $url = '';
    }
    return $url;
}
```

But since the refresh is not wanted either, let's allow the form to still submit as normal but simply change it's target attribute.

```
// Capture Single Product Add to Cart Form
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'woo_capture_single_product_add_to_cart_form' );
function woo_capture_single_product_add_to_cart_form() {
    if ( is_tax( 'product_cat' ) ) {
        ob_start();
    }
}

// Modify Single Product Add to Cart Form
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form', 'woo_modify_add_to_cart_form' );
function woo_modify_single_product_add_to_cart_form() {
    if ( is_tax( 'product_cat' ) ) {
        $form = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        $form = str_replace( '<form class="cart"', '<form class="cart" target="background-cart-iframe"', $form );
        echo $form;
    }
}

// -----------------------------
// Background Add to Cart Iframe
// -----------------------------
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'woo_add_background_cart_iframe' );
function woo_add_background_cart_iframe() {
    if ( is_tax( 'product_cat' ) ) {
        echo '<iframe id="background-cart-iframe" name="background-cart-iframe" src="javascript:void(0);" style="display:none;"></iframe>';
    }
}
```

Note the `is_tax( 'product_cat' )` check in each function makes this run only on product archive pages, to make it work elsewhere (eg. shop page) you'd have to add/modify that condition.

Depending on what theme/plugin you have installed this all may prevent the customer from seeing that the product was successfully added to cart. But for example we had Woo Side Cart plugin already installed (with auto-open disabled) and it worked fine.